# Try-catch simulink errors

Tags: matlab, try-catch, simulink

I have a queue of sim-commands, which will be simulated one after one. In some cases, depending on previous user inputs, Simulink throws out an error, which I want to catch, but try-catch doesn't works, because SIMULINK first opens an own debugger and stops the process.

Does anybody know a way?

Comment: There is always the possibility to do an `if-else` or `switch-case` here. something like `if bad input, doThis; else, doThat;end`

Comment: @patrick There is no way to validate the input data for logical correctnes previously. What I want is `try sim catch doThis`.

Comment: Try-catch works fine with Simulink. See [Error Handling in Simulink Using MSLException](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/error-handling-in-simulink-using-mslexception.html).

Comment: Actually I have, the whole time I have used matlab, only run into one case where try catch have been useful. This is for the save function, since format -v7 is not stable, but loads faster than -v7.3. This is with other words a matlab bug in a mex file and nothing can be done there. It seems you have an unstable algorithm here somewhere. Sorry but I can still not see a reason for using try catch, only a reason to rewrite the code.

Comment: The model is solving a system at every timestep and it's possible that he cant find a solution. In this case the embedded matlab block  throws out an error, but before the program returns to MATLAB a "runtime error" window opens and when i click OK the debugger starts. When I close the debugger, I'm back to MATLAB and the catch block executes. So I have to find a way to suppress the Simulink debugger and immediately return to MATLAB

Comment: any ideas? maybe a option in Simulink to disable debugging?